# java class not compiling code via cmd

Tags: java

I have a Java Class Called `Listenermain.java` which has dependencies on external libraries the class is a s below.

```
import Luxand.FSDK;

import php.java.bridge.JavaBridgeRunner;


public class Listenermain {

public static final String JAVABRIDGE_PORT = "1699";//8080
static final JavaBridgeRunner runner
        = JavaBridgeRunner.getInstance(JAVABRIDGE_PORT);

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 * 
 */
public static void main( String[] args ) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    try {
        System.loadLibrary("facesdk");
        int res = FSDK
                .ActivateLibrary("pZo9jhbhbybgvbh");
        FSDK.Initialize();
        FSDK.SetFaceDetectionParameters(true, true, 384);
        FSDK.SetFaceDetectionThreshold(5);

        if (res == FSDK.FSDKE_OK) {
            System.out.printf("FaceSDK activated", "FaceSDK activated\n");
        } else {
            System.out.printf("Error activating FaceSDK: ", res + "\n");
        }
    } catch (java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
        System.out.printf("exception ", e.getMessage());
    }
    try {
        runner.waitFor();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.printf("Error: ", ex.getMessage() + "\n");
    }
    // System.exit(0);
}

}
```

I compile my class with following on cmd line syntax

```
javac -classpath ".;C:\Users\daviestobialex\Workarea\openshiftmatcher\libs\JavaBridge.jar;C:\Users\daviestobialex\Workarea\openshiftmatcher\libs\FaceSDK.jar;C:\Users\daviestobialex\Workarea\openshiftmatcher\libs\jna.jar" Listenermain.java
```

and it doesn't spit any errors, but when I try to run the code via command line interface again with this syntax

```
`java -classpath . Listenermain`
```

I get the error below

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: php/java/bridge/JavaBridgeRunner at Listenermain.(Listenermain.java:19)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: php.java.bridge.JavaBridgeRunner

So am confused as to why the `Listenermain.class` wasn't compiled with the dependencies I specified.

Comment: You need to mention the dependent libraries path in the run command also, else JVM cannot resolve the dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run the program, you also need to specify the classpath to resolve class dependencies.

Try like that :

```
java -classpath ".;C:\Users\daviestobialex\Workarea\openshiftmatcher\libs\JavaBridge.jar;C:\Users\daviestobialex\Workarea\openshiftmatcher\libs\FaceSDK.jar;C:\Users\daviestobialex\Workarea\openshiftmatcher\libs\jna.jar" Listenermain
```